# to_numeric returns NaN in correlation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called types that contains the letter p or u, I am trying to give these numerical values as follows:

```
df['type'] = df['type'].map({'p': 1, 'u': 2})
df["type"] = pd.to_numeric(df["type"])
```

If I print the df then the type column contains all 1s (currently only p values)

If i try and do a correlation using

```
print mushroomdf.corr(method='spearman')
```

The type value is returned as NaN

[image]

Any idea way to resolve this?

It works for other values in the same file.

Comment: Ummm what is `dr` , should be `df` right?

Comment: @W-B Yes, it should be df, I have update the text, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run a correlation between a constant value, `1`, and another column.  Dig into the mechanics of the Spearman; you'll find a term that requires the variance of each column to be non-zero.  You need at least *one* term different from the others.